# P-value in likelihood ratio test definition

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

According to Williams, D.: Weighing the Odds the p-value of observed data in the likelihood ratio setting is defined as

$$\mathrm{p_{val}}(y^{obs}) := \mathrm{sup}_{\theta \in B_0} \mathbb{P}\big(\mathrm{lr}(Y) \geq \mathrm{lr}(y^{obs}) \vert \theta \big)$$

where

$$ \mathrm{lr}(y) := \frac{\mathrm{sup}_{\theta \in B_A} \mathrm{lhd}(\theta, y)}{\mathrm{sup}_{\theta \in B_0} \mathrm{lhd}(\theta, y)} $$

where $\mathrm{lhd}$ is the likelihood function. He further calls it a 'convoluted concept', which got me thinking what is the reason for this comment. One thing I realized, which I did not realize before, is that in the first equation the supremum can be achieved by a value of $\theta^*$ that could have never generated the $y^{obs}$ (could be $f_{\theta^*}(y^{obs}) = 0).$ So I thought maybe it would make sense to define something like

$$\mathrm{p^{mod}_{val}}(y^{obs}) := \mathrm{sup}_{\theta \in B_0} \bigg (\mathbb{P}\big(\mathrm{lr}(Y) \geq \mathrm{lr}(y^{obs}) \vert \theta \big)  \mathbb{P}(y^{obs} \vert \theta) \bigg )$$

Has this been done before? Does it have some name? What about if we change it to

$$\mathrm{p^{mod 2}_{val}}(y^{obs}) := \mathrm{sup}_{\theta \in B_0} \bigg (\mathbb{P}\big(\mathrm{lr}(Y) \geq \mathrm{lr}(y^{obs}) \vert \theta \big)  \mathbb{I}_{\mathbb{P}(y^{obs} \vert \theta) > 0} \bigg )$$

Answer (score 2):

Motivated by the same issue [Berger and Boos (1994)](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1994.10476836) proposed to maximize over a confidence set for $\theta$ (ie a subset of $B_0$), so may be a good starting point to look.
They give a nice overview of various alternatives that have been proposed and interesting examples where the usual p-value is unsatisfactory (illustrating your point).

Instead of changing the definition of p-value [Lehmann](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-1-4614-1412-4_20.pdf) suggested to replace the usual "maximum likelihood ratio" by an averaged likelihood ratio. He also give interesting examples where the usual approach fails.

In spite of all its possible problems, I keep being surprised how well the usual maximum likelihood ratio test works in many situations.

Comment: (You deleted your previous answer posted a few minutes earlier: I'd recommend next time rather edit the previous answer.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, will do!